# How to hide OneDrive icon from favorites navigation page from Windows 7

Tags: windows

Could you please help me to hide OneDrive icon from user favorites bar from windows 7  as well as Windows 10. (Mostly we are using windows 7 Enterprise edt.)

Answer (score 0):

**Tested on Windows 10.**

To remove, save below code as remove_onedrive.bat

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}]
"System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree"=dword:00000000

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}]
```

To add back onedrive, save the following code as add_onedrive.bat

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}]
"System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}]
@="OneDrive"
```

Comment: mentioned registry value not available in registry.as we are having  Windows Registry Editor Version is 6.1

Comment: The version in a .reg file just means not v4